# how to open camera in a tkinter frame and close only the frame/camera when needed

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I have a tkinter multi-frame application that involves multiple page/frames in one page I want to have a camera using open cv and the camera should close when I navigate to some other screen/page and should start automatically when the frames comes on screen or is in focus
the frame is comming when I navigate to a page but it is not closing and always running in the background when I use `frame.quit()` it closes the whole application but I only want to close that camera

The main class which controls navigation

```
import tkinter as tk
import connectionPage
import startPage
// it has more than 15 pages but for example I have removed others

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        self.geometry(geometry)
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        StartPage=startPage.StartPage
        ConnectionPage=connectionPage.connect_page
        FrontCameraPage = frontCameraPage.FrontCameraPage
        for F in (StartPage, ConnectionPage,FrontCameraPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(startPage.StartPage)
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        if hasattr(frame, 'refresh'):
            frame.refresh()
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tkinterApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

my camera frame/page

```
class FrontCameraPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="FRONT CAMERA", font=MediumFont, bg="white").grid(row = 0,column = 0,columnspan=2, sticky = "nsew")
        self.cameraFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg=gray)
        self.cameraFrame.grid(row = 1,column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.buttonFrame  = tk.Frame(self,bg = "white")
        self.buttonFrame.grid(row = 1,column = 1, sticky = "nsew",padx = (10,0))

        def end_trip():
            self.cameraFrame.quit()# right now i am using quit but it is closing whole applicaiton i just want to close camera 



        self.Info = tk.Label(self.buttonFrame, text="FACE NOT\n DETECTED", font=MediumFont,bg = dark_red,fg ="white")
        self.Info.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=8,pady = (0,5))
        
        self.switchCamera = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="SWITCH CAMERA", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, command=lambda: self.switch_camera(),fg ="white")
        self.switchCamera.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=5,pady = (0,5))

        self.endTrip = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="END TRIP", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, command=pass = "White")
        self.endTrip.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=10,pady = (0,5))

        self.cancelButton = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Cancel", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, command=pass,fg="white")
        self.cancelButton.grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=10)
        


    def refresh(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        width, height = 200, 200
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
        lmain = tk.Label(self.cameraFrame)
        lmain.pack()

        def show_frame():
            _, frame = cap.read()
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            lmain.imgtk = imgtk
            lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
            lmain.after(10, show_frame)
        show_frame()
```

the camera should close when I change the frame and go to another frame or click any button.

Comment: in all `Pages` you should create functions `before()`, `after()` and in main `show_frame()` you should run `frame.after()` , .... old code  ,`frame.before()` - so every page could run some code when you change pages. And `FrontCameraPage` could use `before()` to open camera, and `after()` to close camera.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is to use *virtual events* to notify the camera frame when it is being switched in or out.

When the camera frame receives those *virtual events*, it can then start or stop the capturing based on the type of the event.

Below is the modified `FrontCameraPage`:

```py
class FrontCameraPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="FRONT CAMERA", font=MediumFont, bg="white").grid(row = 0,column = 0,columnspan=2, sticky = "nsew")
        self.cameraFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg=gray)
        self.cameraFrame.grid(row = 1,column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.buttonFrame  = tk.Frame(self,bg = "white")
        self.buttonFrame.grid(row = 1,column = 1, sticky = "nsew",padx = (10,0))

        self.Info = tk.Label(self.buttonFrame, text="FACE NOT\n DETECTED", font=MediumFont,bg = dark_red,fg ="white")
        self.Info.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=8,pady = (0,5))

        self.switchCamera = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="SWITCH CAMERA", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, command=lambda: self.switch_camera(),fg ="white")
        self.switchCamera.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=5,pady = (0,5))

        self.endTrip = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="END TRIP", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, fg = "White")
        self.endTrip.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=10,pady = (0,5))
        self.endTrip['command'] = self.stop_capture

        self.cancelButton = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Cancel", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, fg="white")
        self.cancelButton.grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=10)
        self.cancelButton['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(startPage.StartPage)

        # setup callbacks for switching in and out events
        self.bind('<<SwitchIn>>', self.start_capture)
        self.bind('<<SwitchOut>>', self.stop_capture)

        self.capture = None  # task id for the capture loop

        # label for showing the captured image
        self.lmain = tk.Label(self.cameraFrame)
        self.lmain.pack()

    def start_capture(self, event=None):
        if self.capture is None:
            # create the capture object
            width, height = 200, 200
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
            self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
            # start the capture loop
            self.show_frame()
            print('capture started')

    def stop_capture(self, event=None):
        if self.capture:
            # stop the capture loop
            self.after_cancel(self.capture)
            self.capture = None
            # release the capture object
            self.cap.release()
            print('capture stopped')

    def show_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            self.lmain.configure(image=self.imgtk)
        self.capture = self.after(10, self.show_frame)
```

And below is the modified `tkinterApp`:

```py
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        ...

        self.frame = None # the current frame shown
        self.show_frame(startPage.StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        if self.frame:
            # trigger the switching out handler of the frame
            self.frame.event_generate('<<SwitchOut>>')
        self.frame = self.frames[cont]
        self.frame.tkraise()
        # trigger the switching in handler of the frame
        self.frame.event_generate('<<SwitchIn>>')

    ...
```

Update: create `self.cap` inside `start_capture()` and release it inside `stop_capture()`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time but i am getting this error. i exactly copy pasted your code but getting this  ```AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'event_generate'``` while running the application.

Comment: It seems like there is a class method named `frame` inside class `tkinterApp`, otherwise you won't get such error.  Which is the line causing the error?

Comment: this line is causing error ```self.frame.event_generate('<<SwitchOut>>')``` and I have posted full code of ```tkinterApp``` you can see there is no function name frame.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:tkinterApp.py", line 74, in <module>
    app = tkinterApp()
  File "d:tkinterApp.py", line 42, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "d:backCameraPage.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.cancelButton = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="CANCEL", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, command=controller.show_frame(dashboardPage.dashboard_page),fg="white")
  File "d:tkinterApp.py", line 58, in show_frame
    self.frame.event_generate('<<SwitchOut>>')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'event_generate ```

Comment: @stark You need to add the updated code with my suggested changes and the traceback in your question.

Comment: yes i fixed this issue but the camera  is not stopping i guess because the camera light of my laptop is always running after that front camera frame and never stops even if  I change the frame

Comment: Note that my suggestion will only stop the capture loop, the capture object `self.vid` is still open.  May be you need to release the capture object inside `stop_capture()`.  In this case, you need to create the capture object inside `start_capture()`.

Comment: yes I need that

Comment: can you edit your answer for what I want

Comment: @stark Answer updated.